# R ggplot2 Multiple Lines in Connected Scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I need to plot multiple lines in a connected scatterplot, but am running into issues. I can plot one line, but not the other (or more).

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)

year<-c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019)

variableA1<-c(56,169,313,595,797,989,934,869,824,662)
variableB1<-c(0,0,5,12,23,44,73,71,78,103)

variableA2<-c(22,58,159,342,603,1021,1589,2071,2268,2044)
variableB2<-c(1,1,0,3,7,9,33,59,84,98)


data<-data.frame(year,variableA1,variableB1,variableA2,variableB2)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=variableA1, y=variableB1, label=year)) +
     geom_point(color="#333333") + 
     geom_text_repel() +
     geom_segment(color="#333333", 
                aes(
                    xend=c(tail(variableA1, n=-1), NA), 
                    yend=c(tail(variableB1, n=-1), NA)
                ),
                arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))
                ) +
     geom_point(color="#a8a8a8") + 
     geom_text_repel() +
     geom_segment(color="#a8a8a8", 
                aes(
                    xend=c(tail(variableA2, n=-1), NA), 
                    yend=c(tail(variableB2, n=-1), NA)
                ),
                arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))
                )
```

**ggplot Chart**

[image: Connected Scatterplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the way to do things with `ggplot2`.

Instead, you define the x and y coordinates for both series in the same columns and add another column that specifies which data series the values belong to.

#### EDIT

The segment coordinates (for the arrows) should also be set explicitly for each data series:

```
data_points<-data.frame(year = year, varA = variableA1, varB = variableB1, series = "series1") %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(year = year, varA = variableA2, varB = variableB2, series = "series2"))

data_lines<-data.frame(
    x = head(variableA1, n=-1),
    y = head(variableB1, n=-1),
    xend = tail(variableA1, n=-1),
    yend = tail(variableB1, n=-1),
    series = "series1") %>%
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(
      x = head(variableA2, n=-1), 
      y = head(variableB2, n=-1), 
      xend = tail(variableA2, n=-1),
      yend = tail(variableB2, n=-1), 
      series = "series2")
  )

data_points %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=varA, y=varB, label=year, color=series)) +
  geom_point(color="#333333") + 
  geom_text_repel() +
  geom_segment(data = data_lines,
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, 
                   color = series, label=NA),
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))
  ) +
  scale_color_manual( values = c('#333333', '#a8a8a8'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That seems closer to what I was looking for, but how do I avoid that this is one continuous graph? In the figure above, 2019 in the first series is connected to 2010 of the second series. I need them to be two "separate" lines.

Comment: You're righ @Rahul, the start and end coordinates of the line segments are still off. They need to be specified differently. I'll have a look a bit later.

Comment: Have a look now. I edited the answer to include the correct coordinates for the arrow segments.